# How to group data of one dataframe by matching the condition on another dataframe, when both the dataframes has exactly same columns and index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, say df1 like this:

```
    1   2   3   4   
1   5   2   3   14  
2   20  18  12  16  
3   13  21  32  4  
4   17  25  32  13
```

and another dataframe, say df2 like this:

```
    1   2   3   4 
1   13  19  45  56 
2   45  54  28  31
3   33  45  32  9
4   23  65  14  15
```

I want to fill this third dataframe, say df3:

```
Lower   Upper   Val
0       5       73
5       10      13
10      15      132
15      20      ...
20      25      ...
25      30      ...
```

Now, to fill the 'val' column in df3, the code should first get the cell locations in df1 which lies between the given limits in df3 and then adds the corresponding values of df2 not df1.

I could able to do it using nested-loops but I need something without loops.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add expcted output of column `Val` ?

Comment: I have added the values for first three rows

Comment: how do you obtain 73? we need the logic

Comment: 73 = (19+45+9) adding values of df2
but limits are matched in df1 (2,3,4) which is between 0-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create [`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) from `Lower` and `Upper` columns. Then reshape first and second DataFrames by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for first use binning by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) used for groups for aggregation by `sum`:

```
df3.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df3['Lower'], df3['Upper'], closed='left')
print (df3.index)
IntervalIndex([[0, 5), [5, 10), [10, 15), [15, 20), [20, 25), [25, 30)],
              closed='left',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

df3['Val'] = df2.stack().groupby(pd.cut(df1.stack(), df3.index)).sum()
print (df3)
          Lower  Upper  Val
[0, 5)        0      5   73
[5, 10)       5     10   13
[10, 15)     10     15  132
[15, 20)     15     20  108
[20, 25)     20     25   90
[25, 30)     25     30   65
```

Last create default index:

```
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df3)
   Lower  Upper  Val
0      0      5   73
1      5     10   13
2     10     15  132
3     15     20  108
4     20     25   90
5     25     30   65
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1.stack())
1  1     5
   2     2
   3     3
   4    14
2  1    20
   2    18
   3    12
   4    16
3  1    13
   2    21
   3    32
   4     4
4  1    17
   2    25
   3    32
   4    13
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (pd.cut(df1.stack(), df3.index))
1  1     [5.0, 10.0)
   2      [0.0, 5.0)
   3      [0.0, 5.0)
   4    [10.0, 15.0)
2  1    [20.0, 25.0)
   2    [15.0, 20.0)
   3    [10.0, 15.0)
   4    [15.0, 20.0)
3  1    [10.0, 15.0)
   2    [20.0, 25.0)
   3             NaN
   4      [0.0, 5.0)
4  1    [15.0, 20.0)
   2    [25.0, 30.0)
   3             NaN
   4    [10.0, 15.0)
dtype: category
Categories (6, interval[int64]): [[0, 5) < [5, 10) < [10, 15) < [15, 20) < [20, 25) < [25, 30)]
```

---

```
print (df2.stack())
1  1    13
   2    19
   3    45
   4    56
2  1    45
   2    54
   3    28
   4    31
3  1    33
   2    45
   3    32
   4     9
4  1    23
   2    65
   3    14
   4    15
dtype: int64
```